# Is it possible to bind a TableLayout with a ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-tablelayout

Is it possible to bind a TableLayout with a ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no such API in the framework. You can do it manually by querying the adapter yourself. Something like this:

```
int count = adapter.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    tableLayout.addView(createTableRow(adapter.getItem(i)); // or tableLayout.addView(adapter.getView(i, null, tableLayout));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do i ensure that the views are getting recycled as that of the convert View?

Comment: You can't unless you are willing to reimplement a view recycler like ListView's, and trust me, it's a lot of work you don't want to do :p