# Adding a fragment to the end of the activity on scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments

I simplified my code to make it more understandable. I am reading some data from a database and insert in Table Rows. Since there are thousands of entries it takes time to load and freezes the UI. What I want is to move the process in a Fragment, changing the SQL query to load only 100 entries every time. I want this fragment to be added to the end of the activity every time we reach the end of the scroll. Is that possible to easily implement?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.order_det_v2);
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.prodTable);
    newProductButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newProductButton);


    //creates and open the database so we can use it
    dataBase = DataBaseManager.instance();


    Cursor cursor = dataBase.select("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRODUCTS_ID));


        TextView textProdCode = new TextView(order_det_v2.this);
        textProdCode.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 60, 0.08f));
        textProdCode.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.row_background1));
        textProdCode.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textProdCode.setTextSize(18);

        tr.addView(textProdCode);

        String code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRODUCTS_CODE));

        textProdCode.append(" " + code + "\n");


        tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(order_det_v2.this, order_det_v2.class);
                intent.putExtra("currentProduct", currentProductID);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong practice bro. Just use Listview for smoother loading. Even there is lacks of entries Listview will handle properly

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I simplified my code, but I need add different data to a row, so a list view is not possible.

Comment: why not possible? Who told you that you can not add different data to row in listview

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I just read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757083/does-android-have-a-table-like-adapter-for-listview. I thought it concerned my problem. I am new to Android development and can't understand some concepts.